# JavaScript: Transforming a multi-dimensional array into a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a JS array that's filled with data as follows:

```
var myarr = [[new Date("2011-12-01"), 389, 380.75, 382.54, 387.93],
[new Date("2011-11-30"), 382.28, 378.3, 381.29, 382.2]...]
```

Is there some way to only select the entire date column and the last number of each row? I'm looking for an output that's something like this:

```
[[new Date("2011-12-01"), 387.93],[new Date("2011-11-30"), 382.2]...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myCollapsedArr = [[myarr[0][0], myarr[0][myarr[0].length-1]], [myarr[1][0], myarr[1][myarr[1].length-1]];
```

Or in a for loop:

```
var myCollapsedArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i<myarr.length; i++) {
    myCollapsedArr.push([myarr[i], [myarr[i][myarr[i].length-1]]);
}
```

Comment: Note that it's a good practice to cache the length of your array in the loop setup, otherwise you're re-calculating it every time. Not a big speed hit, but never a bad idea. `for (var i=0,len=myarr.length;i<len;++i) …`

Comment: Thanks, Elliot. The loop worked. Although I was thinking that there might be some function such as slice that does it without making use of loops. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - Simple for Loop**

```
// Create array to hold new values
var newArray = [];
// Loop through existing array and pull out data
for(var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
    newArray.push([myarr[i][0], myarr[i][myarr[i].length - 1]]);
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/tkW2J/) to demonstrate.

**Option 2 - ECMAScript 5 [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

```
// Create array to hold new values
var newArray = [];

// Loop through existing array and pull out data
myarr.forEach(function(obj) {
    newArray.push([obj[0], obj[obj.length - 1]]);
});
```

​Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/Gucs4/) to demonstrate.